# Manually parse a portion of dynamic JSON object alongside Gson deserializer

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

I want to parse the following JSON response with a dynamic JSON object,

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "last_login": "2016-07-16T12:46:29.621996Z",
  "point_of_sales": [
    {
      "Counter 4": {
        "type": "retail",
        "id": 6
      }
    },
    {
      "Counter 5": {
        "type": "retail",
        "id": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "Counter 6": {
        "type": "retail",
        "id": 8
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the objects name inside "**point_of_sales**" array are dynamic which makes it difficult to parse using Gson. Here's what I've tried so far,

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("last_login")
@Expose
private String lastLogin;
@SerializedName("point_of_sales")
@Expose
private List<Map<String, Counter>> pointOfSales = new ArrayList<Map<String, Counter>>();

.......

getter & setters
```

Counter class,

```
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;

.......

getter & setters
```

By following this procedure I can convert the objects but can't extract them from map to the pojo classes.

```
 for (Map<String, Counter> objectMap : response.getPointOfSales())
{
// How to extract the Counter pojo data from map list?
}
```

I also tried this way but nothing works,

```
ArrayList<Counter> pojos = new ArrayList<Counter>();
                    try {
                        for (Map<String, Counter> objectMap : result.getPointOfSales()) {
                            Counter pojo = new Counter();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, Counter> property : objectMap.entrySet()) {
                                Method setter = Counter.class.getMethod("set" + property.getKey().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + property.getKey().substring(1), property.getValue().getClass());
                                setter.invoke(pojo, property.getValue());
                            }
                            pojos.add(pojo);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    for (Counter pojo : pojos) {
                        Log.e("result", "" + pojo.getId() + " " + pojo.getType());
                    }
```

Is there any way to parse the specific array by using,

1. Gson
2. Using a duel parsing technique to parse the specific portion manually and rest of the response in Gson?

I want to make the dynamic objects wrapped into a pojo class.

Comment: you need a JsonDeserializer for that. If I understand correctly what you want to achieve

Comment: I just want to make the dynamic objects wrapped into a pojo class so that the data of "id",  "type" field can be received easily.

Comment: then I guess a custom [JsonDeserializer](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) is what you need.

Comment: From my example code, I'm not sure if the data's are parsing correctly and can't get the pojo data from the map list. My primary query is to extract all pojo data from the map objects. Can I use a custom JsonDeserializer with regular Gson parsing for normal objects?

Answer (score 1):

You need two things.

1. You need to do a little bit of refactoring on your model classes.
2. You would need to add a JsonDeserializer to handle that dynamic parsing.

Here's how I would do it:

**MainObject.java**

```
.....
@SerializedName("point_of_sales")
SalesPoints mSales Points
.....
```

**SalesPoints.java**

```
private List<Counter>mCounters;
//getter & setters.
```

**Counter.java**

```
SerializedName("type")
private String type;
@SerializedName("id")
private int id; // use primitives instead of boxed primitives
private String mCounterString; // maybe you need it.
```

Now when you will run the parsing you'll have to do something like this:

```
 MainObject object = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(SalesPoints.class, new JsonDeserializer< SalesPoints >() {
        @Override
        public SalesPoints deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            SalesPoints sales = new SalesPoints();
            ArrayList<Counter>counters = new ArrayList<Counter>();
            JsonArray salesJson = json.getAsJsonArray();
            for(JsonElement object : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                   Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> iterator = object.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();
                   while (iterator.hasNext())){
                          Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry = iterator.next();
                            String counterString = entry.getKey();
                            JsonElement counterObject = 
                                                    entry.getValue();
                            Counter counter = context.deserialize(counterObject, Counter.class);
                            counter.setCounterString(counterString);
                            counters.add(counter);
                        }          
            }
            sales.setCounters(counters);
            return sales;
        }
    }).create().fromJson(theJson);
```

Now when the `MainObject` is parsed it will contain the `SalesPoints` that contains all the counters.

NOTE: I might misspelled some words, or I might forgot to add some `getAs..` methods because I didn't have the possibility to test the code, but this is the way to go and you can easily debug it.

**EDIT**

For retrofit you'll need to do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(SalesPoints.class, new JsonDeserializer< SalesPoints >() {
        @Override
        public SalesPoints deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            SalesPoints sales = new SalesPoints();
            ArrayList<Counter>counters = new ArrayList<Counter>();
            JsonArray salesJson = json.getAsJsonArray();
            for(JsonElement object : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                   Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> iterator = object.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();
                   while (iterator.hasNext())){
                          Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry = iterator.next();
                            String counterString = entry.getKey();
                            JsonElement counterObject = 
                                                    entry.getValue();
                            Counter counter = context.deserialize(counterObject, Counter.class);
                            counter.setCounterString(counterString);
                            counters.add(counter);
                        }          
            }
            sales.setCounters(counters);
            return sales;
        }
    }).create();


new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))//set remaining things fro your retrofit builder.
```

Comment: What is "theJson" & "entry" ? Actually I'm using Retrofit 2 to make the parsing & api callback process. I'm kinda confused about where & how to use the JsonDeserializer with Retrofit.